# refreshing a page after deletion Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page filled with a list from a database, when clicking any element of this list, the details of this element will appear on another page to be edited. user also have the option of deletion here.
the problem is after deletion process completes the original page with the list doesnt refresh, so it still displays the deleted element in the list.
i tried different methods mentioned here in stackoverflow.com but none worked as i want.
for example this answer was mentioned here:

```
$sql = "delete from `lesson_plans` where `LP_ID` = '" . $_SESSION['LP_ID_S']."';";  
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
    {    
        echo "<script>var hWndB = window.open('myplans.php'),
                hWndA = window.self;
                hWndB.onunload = function(){ hWndA.location.reload(); }
              </script>";
    }
```

the problem in this code that is opens a new page with new list successfully and keeps the old one open as well, so it doesnt refresh the old one, it only open a new link in a new tab.

Comment: you have to refresh list using ajax after few second ...so it list option is delted from another page it will be removed

Comment: thaks for the answer but its not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh page in php add the below code
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if header already exist error comes then add the ob_start() in top of the page

you need to refresh page in javascript then add below code

location.reload();

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this using windows.redirect you can reload the page.

```
$sql = "delete from `lesson_plans` where `LP_ID` = '" . $_SESSION['LP_ID_S']."';";  
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{    
    echo "<script> window.location = "myplans.php"; </script>";
}
```

Comment: it does the same as my code, it doesnt refresh the old page! thank you though